# Regular expression alternative for javascript escape() function

Tags: javascript, regex, jmeter

I'm working on Jmeter, and I need to send an encoded parameter along with the Http request.
I know that I can do the encoding of special characters using javascript escape(). But I can't use javascript here, as I'm using Jmeter's Regular Expression Extractor. I need a regular expression pattern that does the same as escape(). Please do help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions can't do this. `escape()` (which is deprecated anyway and has been superseded by `encodeURI()`) takes ASCII control characters and non-ASCII characters and encodes them using `%xx` or `%uxxxx` hexadecimal notation. Regular expressions can only work with existing text, not convert it.

Comment: I'm surprised to know that. Thanks for that.
Can you please help me in finding a way that I can encode a string in Jmeter, in the same way as escape() does.

Answer (score 1):

New upcoming version 2.10 of jmeter will have a new function that does it:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54991